# Creating a new dataframe based on rows of an existing dataframe which contain only specific characters

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In Python I am trying to create a new dataframe by appending all rows which do not contain certain
charachters in a certain column of another dataframe. Afterwards I want the generated list containing the results into a dataframe.
However, this result only contains a one column dataframe and does not include all the columns of the first dataframe (which do not contain those characters, which is what I need).
Does anybody have a suggestion on how to add all the columns to a new dataframe?

```
%%time
newlist = []
for row in old_dataframe['column']:
    if row != (r'^[^\s]') :
        newlist.append(row)
```

Comment: it would be good to have some example data of your `old_dataframe['column']` in your question, a few rows is fine.

Comment: it's generally considered bad practice to loop through a dataframe, you might be able to use `.str.contains()` and `.loc` to achieve this better, but it's hard to tell without an example of old_dataframe, and the expected output

Comment: You're better off doing this on the dataframe level, using for example `.str.contains()`[https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html]. That will give a boolean series with which you can index the old dataframe, directly obtaining a new dataframe.

Comment: Thanks, The specific column only contains NaN values in this case but in the future might contain any of the characters indicated in the regex statement.